# Is there any way to combine the Slf4jReporter with the metrics-json package to generate JSON in the logs

Tags: java, dropwizard, codahale-metrics

Is there any way to combine the `Slf4jReporter` with the metrics-json package to generate JSON in the logs?

```
reporter = Slf4jReporter.forRegistry(registry)
                        .outputTo(logger)
                        .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .build();
```

Is there any example of registering the metrics-json with reporter/logger.